# VS Code 2 errors: 1st is "Import 'solcx' could not be resolved." 2nd issue is given in terminal as "INFO: Could not find files for the given patterns

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, solidity

Here is the code

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
import json

with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()

    install_solc("0.6.0")

    compiled_sol = compile_standard(
        {
            "language": "Solidity",
            "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
            "settings": {
                "outputSelection": {
                    "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
                }
            },
        },
        solc_version="0.6.0",
    )

with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)
```

In the terminal, I have ran the commands of:  `pip3 install py-solc-x` and `pip install solc` and get a response that the requirement is already satisfied separately for both commands.

I also get the error of INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s). when I run the command of `python deploy.py`

This is how by VS Code folder looks like on my Local Disk:
[the python source file and SOL file are in the same folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ictMJ.jpg)

As you can probably tell, I am very new as I'm taking freeCodeCamps beginners course. Any and all help is great appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is for resolving the first error:
Exit from any virtual environments by running "deactivate" (or "conda deactivate" for exiting from an Anaconda virtual environment).

Run python3 from the terminal

Run these lines of code as follows:

```
  import solcx

  solcx.install_solc() #or you can install a specific version by running "solcx.install_solc('0.6.0')"(without the quotes) or any other version in the brackets.
```

As for the second error, check if the SimpleStorage.sol file is present in the same directory as the given python code file. And also the "compiled_code.json" file will automatically be created in the same folder as that of the given python file(due to the "w" argument present in the open function).

Answer (score 0):

Could you check where you have installed the modules? `pip3 show py-solc-x`.

And check which python interpreter you have selected from the bottom-left on the VSCode:

[image]

You can click it to select the python interpreter or reinstall the modules in the environment you have selected.

And from your image, it's a little weird about your filename. Your file was named `SimpleStorage.sol` while another file was named `deploy` and its type was `Python Source File`. So you look like have hidden the filename extension, so your file name needs to be `SimpleStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

import solcx

solcx.install_solc("0.6.0")

this worked for me